# C++ std::length_error when using ternary operator?

Tags: c++, string, conditional-operator

I was using C++ to work on a LeetCode problem in which I wanted to give the std::sort() a custom lambda comparator:

```
sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](string& a, string& b){
   return (a+b < b+a) ? false : true;        
});
```

When my code was tested on the following test case:

```
//Edited:Assume this is an array of string, not int
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

The compiler gave me the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
```

I then looked into other people's solutions, and found that what they wrote for the ternary operator was instead:

```
return a+b > b+a;
```

The above code compiled properly without any errors. I was wondering if anyone could shed a light on why my original code did not work?

Comment: @Yunnosch How so?

Comment: _"I was wondering if anyone could shed a light on why my original code did not work?"_ Perhaps we could, if we could see it. Show us your [mcve].

Comment: Are you sorting a vector of ints or strings?

Comment: @Shawn It literally says string in the code.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The given test case is a bunch of 0's, no strings in sight.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I am sorting a std::vector<std::string>

Comment: And since `std::string(0)` is equivalent to `std::string(nullptr)`, which is undefined, a strange exception or other mysterious behavior isn't too unexpected if OP is trying to treat ints like strings.

Comment: @Shawn: Um... _"sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](string& a, string& b){"_ ???

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I probably am missing something but for me `a+b == b+a` and can neither be `>` nor  `<`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't know where you're getting that from, but [it's trivially false](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/756aea1d017e2f69)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Simple explanation I was (wrongly of course) thinking of integers. I said I was confused. ;-)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings *The following test case `[0,0,0,...`*

Comment: @Shawn So? `[` isn't an `int` either. Not sure why you're fixating on the manner in which the OP formatted their input data for the question. The comparator would make zero sense for anything but strings, and the code _clearly_ indicates that `string`s are being sorted. ‍♂️ They have also now confirmed that for you, so let's move on.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings See my other comments about string constructors and undefined behavior. All depends on how OP is goes from those 0's to strings. If you still can't see the issue, I give up.

Comment: @Shawn You're imagining it. Why would the OP construct strings from ints? That makes no sense. It would also only even _compile_ on literals, so their entire program would only be able to accept this one, hardcoded testcase. And, if it were hardcoded literals, it wouldn't look like this because C++ doesn't let you write vectors of ints like `[0,0,0,0,0]` in source code. It's just.. nonsense! I don't know why you're fixating on this so-called "possibility". But, sure, try to turn it around on me like I "can't see the issue". ‍♂️ Cya!

Comment: Sorry again for the confusion here. Let us assume that [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] is an array of strings, instead of ints

Answer (score 3):

Your comparator does not meet the [requirements for comparators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). For example, if `a` and `b` are both `"X"`, `a+b` and `b+a` are `"XX"`. Then, both `comp(a,b)` and `comp(b,a)` return `true` in your case, and `comp(a,a)` is `true`, which violates the rules for comparators. Namely, these particular rules:

> - For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`
> - If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false`

You may change the comparator to something that defines a *strict weak ordering*, such as:

```
[](const string& a, const string& b)
{
  return (a + b > b + a);
}
```

Note that this comparator does not return `true` if the strings are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understand the requirements for comparators now. But besides this, why was my code causing the "std::length_error"?

Comment: @MikeL Because when you break the C++ rules, typically it implies _undefined behavior_. Asking about undefined behavior usually does not make sense. To understand what actually happens you might need to study the all involved source code and the generated assembly.